# How to repeat a function call n times

Tags: scheme

I'm trying to create a function that wraps itself `n` times using a function called `repeat`

```
(define (repeat f n)
  (if (= n 1)
      f
      (repeat (lambda (x) (f x)) (- n 1))))

((repeat inc 5) 2)
```

I'm expecting the result to be equal to

```
(inc (inc (inc (inc (inc 2))))) ; 7
```

But my result is `3`

What am I doing wrong?

---

To be clear, I want `repeat` to return a function that accepts a single argument. `f` should not be applied until the return value of `repeat` is called with an argument.

e.g.,

```
(define inc5 (repeat inc 5))
(inc5 2) ; => 7
```

p.s.,

This is *related* but not *identical* to exercise 1.43 in [SICP](https://github.com/sarabander/sicp-pdf). I've solved the problem as it is presented there, but I'm curious if it can be solved this way too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take a look at a similar function.

```
(define (repeat-exp fn ct)
  (if (= ct 1)
      fn
      (repeat `(lambda (x) (,fn x)) (- ct 1))))
```

Calling it will get you

```
> (repeat-exp inc 5)
'(lambda (x)
   ((lambda (x)
      ((lambda (x)
         ((lambda (x) 
            ((lambda (x) 
               (#<procedure:inc> x))
             x))
          x))
       x))
    x))
>
```

As you can see, your initial function only gets called once; in the innermost evaluation. If you want it to get called at each level, you need to call it there too.

```
(define (repeat-exp2 fn ct)
  (if (= ct 1)
      fn
      `(lambda (x) 
         (,fn (,(repeat-exp2 fn (- ct 1)) x)))))

> (repeat-exp2 inc 5)
'(lambda (x)
   (#<procedure:inc>
    ((lambda (x)
       (#<procedure:inc>
        ((lambda (x)
           (#<procedure:inc>
            ((lambda (x)
               (#<procedure:inc> 
                (#<procedure:inc> x)))
             x)))
         x)))
     x)))
>
```

Now you can write the numeric equivalent.

```
(define (repeat2 fn ct)
  (if (= ct 1)
      fn
      (lambda (x) 
        (fn ((repeat2 fn (- ct 1)) x)))))
```

which should do what you wanted initially.

```
> (repeat2 inc 5)
#<procedure>
> ((repeat2 inc 5) 2)
7
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your definition is that `(lambda (x) (f x))` is the same as `f`, i.e., your `repeat` repeats only once.

I think what you need is

```
(define (repeat f n)
  (if (= n 1)
      f
      (lambda (x) (f ((repeat f (- n 1)) x)))))
```

PS. Note that you are using Scheme syntax under the Common Lisp tag; you might want to update one or the other.

Comment: Which syntax is not common lisp?

Comment: `(define (repeat f x) ...)` should be `(defun repeat (f x) ...)`